# Cannot figure out how to reach to a js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path, web-deployment

I am new to web developing and I am trying node.js with express.

I have the following directory structure:

**First App**
----**node_modules**
----**public**
--------**scripts**
------------*additems.js*
----**views**
--------*home.ejs*
----*app.js*

with bold is a folder and italic is a file.

this is the file additem.js:

```
console.log("js connected");
alert("test");
```

and this is home.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test Node</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Dynamic Page</h1>
<p></p>

<ol id='olist'>Names List</ol>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/scripts/additems.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/scripts/additems.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/additems.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/additems.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="additems.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/scripts/additems.js"></script> -->

<p>After Script tag</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

console.log("Server has been started!");

//app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    //res.send("Home Page");
     res.render("home.ejs");

 })
```

I can see that the server can run and the home.ejs is displayed but no sign that additem.js can be even touched.

**What am I missing out?**

Note: I tried different paths to the script, and tried app.use in the app.js with no luck, I also spend considerable amount of time searching the net and I found similar examples that seems to work with no problem.

Output:

console:
Server has been started!

Browser: (**No alerts appear**)

[image]

**UPDATE 1**:
I tried the `../` but it is not working either. in the chrome console I can see this erro: 
`(X) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` but after ading `..\` the error is:
`(X) GET http://localhost:3000/public/scripts/additems.js net::ERR_ABORTED`

Comment: perhaps try '../public/scripts/additems.js' as home.ejs is on folder down from the public folder... move up folders with ../ one, ../../ two etc.

Comment: You need to go up a folder by doing `../` and then the rest of the path to the file, as Herald said.

Comment: - first of all check whether your public folder is already being served
you see that in the chrome console, / network tab.

second if your file is served try to use relative paths.

Comment: I tried the ` ../ ` but it is not working either. in the chrome console I can see this erro: (X) `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: `// app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));` Why is this commented out? You need to serve these static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serve static files from public directory:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "public"));
```

Then, `public` will now be the root directory when accessing these files from a browser.

In other words public will be **`/`**

So to access `additems.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='/scripts/additems.js'></script>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure, I have tried this the first thing. but it seems that there was some other errors that prevented file from being processed. but at least it is reached now. However, I wonder why it is not working without the app.use?

Comment: Because `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "public"));` explicitly makes any file in that directory accessible to anyone browsing your website.  You control what you want to make publicly accessible on your web app.  In `home.ejs` you are trying to access resources that have not been served by express.